# jQuery selector to JSON object representation

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, regex, object

I'm interested in taking a jQuery selector string (the stuff you put inside `$()`) and generating a JSON object from it of all of the elements specified in the string. **I am not interested in selecting from the DOM**.

This kind of thing must happen under the hood with jQuery, is there a public function I can use to achieve this? Is there any open-source libraries that offer this functionality?

Given the following input strings:

- `input[class=wood][name=cedar]`
- `input[class='wood'][name='cedar']`
- `input[class="wood"][name="cedar"]`

I'd like to return the following output:

```
{
  [
    elementType: 'input',
    attributes: [
      class: 'wood',
      name: 'cedar'
    ]
  ]
}
```

And given the following string:

- `input, div`
- `input,div`

I'd like :

```
{
  [
    elementType: 'input'
  ],
  [
    elementType: 'div'
  ]
}
```

It's quite a complicated regex if I have to write it myself and I'd much rather not have to reinvent the wheel :)

Comment: You can always create an in-memory HTML element. That element *is* a HTMLElement Object with properties and values. Than you can say `this.food = "soup"` etc, bu you'll have to build that your self.

Comment: But I hope you realize that both `type > wood` and `food > soup` are *invalid* Element Properties.

Comment: This is why I specified I'm not selecting from the DOM. For the purposes of the example it doesn't matter. I can throw `data-` in front of the attributes if you'd like @RokoC.Buljan.

Comment: I think you're probably asking an XY question. What are you actually up to? I'm asking cause if you explain what you're trying to do - probably there's a better solution than the one you initially thought would be best.

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan This is not an XY question. I want to create something BRAND NEW using the existing jQuery selector syntax.

Comment: Sorry but *`" I want to create something BRAND NEW"`* is most likely an XY question :)

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan Your insinuating that the question I have or the functionality that I'm looking for is invalid. I'm telling you that I'm interested in this functionality as specified input and output because I want this functionality. I don't understand how this can be an XY question. When what I've outline is a function and not a solution to a problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's element and attribute support, the full-range of jQuery selector syntax will complicate this much further.

Here's a jsBin of the code in action [Example](http://jsbin.com/tizosa/5/edit?js,console).

```
var main = {}

main.getAttributes = function (selector) {
  var attributes = selector.match(/(\[[^\]]*\])/g)
  return _.chain(attributes).map(function (attribute) {
    attribute = attribute.match(/\[(.+)\]/)[1]
    attribute = attribute.split('=')
    var key = attribute[0]
    var value = attribute[1].replace(/['"]+/g, '', '')
    return [key, value]
  }).object().value()
}

main.parseSelector = function (selectorStr) {
  var selectors = selectorStr.split(',')
  return _.map(selectors, function (selector) {
    selector = selector.replace(/^\s+|\s$/, '')
    return {
      'elementType': selector.match(/([^\[\]]*)/)[0],
      'attributes': main.getAttributes(selector)
    }
  })
}

var selectorStr = 'input[type=checkbox][class=fun]'
var obj = main.parseSelector(selectorStr)

console.log(obj)
```

Answer (score 0):

Sure, can be done :

```
var query = $("input, div")
var selector = [];

query.selector.split(',').forEach(function(element){
 selector.push({"element": element})
});

console.log(selector)
```

Will give you :

```
[
  {
    elementType: 'input'
  },
  {
    elementType: 'div'
  }
]
```

Here is a working [example](https://jsfiddle.net/vvxbj3bw/1/)

**How this works:**

You can inspect any jQuery selector object and you will find a property called `selector`. This is the string representation of the query. Just come up with right parser for the JSON structure you need, and you are done.

Comment: Thanks for this, but this isn't want I'm looking for. I need more-or-less the full set of jQuery selectors like individual elements as you have here but I also need attribute selectors and in the first example in my question. Which is a much harder regex to write. I started with `.+\[(.+)\]` and realized I'd rather not invent the whole thing from scratch.